# Ajax set variables in realtime, and/or toggle switch depending on a .txt file

Tags: jquery, ajax, file, variables, real-time

i am currently making a web interface for home automation. I am able to turn lights on and off, but with two separate buttons. I want to make one button that is either on or off and gets it's state from a file on the server. The file is something like this:

```
1001 = 0
1002 = 1
1003 = 0
```

Note: the left number is the id of the light and the right number is the state

<strike>When the button is clicked a shell command is executed and the state of the clicked id changes inside the .txt file</strike> (which i got to work). Now i want to see that the change, without reloading of course, from all devices that have the page open.

I was able to get the content from the file and display the text, but I haven't had success with setting the variables: 1001, 1002, 1003,... to '0' or '1'. 
Is a simple .txt file the right choice?

Or is there a way to test for the status for each specific id if it is true or false, without having to set variables?

Can you help me do this?
Thank you.

Comment: I think it could be better to change your file from txt to json and use the json file to simplify the parsing process. If that's not possible you need to write a simple parser for your text file that runs at sets variables right after you get your file over ajax

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly call a shell script using ajax/javascript. User some server such as `appache` and a server side scripting language like PHP in case of `appache`(I recommend installing `wamp/xamp/lamp`). You can call your shell script using php code using shell_exec() or can use directly use php file writing function to read and write the file. This PHP file can be easily called via AJAX with suitable parameters.

I have done a similar project for my college where I turned on and off a led using arduino and gprs module to send command through internet to a web server.

If you are interesting in executing shell commands from js you need to be very platform specific. In Windows Scripting, you do things like:

```
var shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
shell.Run("command here");
```

Comment: Then you can consider calling the shell script from PHP using `shell_exec()` Javascript can't directly call your shell script without any middleware. [also check recent edit in the answer]